# set option style on load for select element

Tags: javascript, html, css, html-select

I have the following on load of my web page:

```
<script>     
function updateStateSelectColor(){
  var elm = document.getElementById("state");
  elm.style.color="black";
}
</script>

<select id="state" onchange="updateStateSelectColor()">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="FL" selected>Florida</option>
</select>
```

What I want is when the page loads for the selected text inside the state select box to be bolded black just like my onchange function that blackens the text. **The problem is my JavaScript is only for onchange not onload**.

Comment: Just call the function right after the declaration. `function updateStateSelectColor(){
  var elm = document.getElementById("state");
  elm.style.color="black";
} updateStateSelectColor();` or use `onload`

Comment: @bassxzero duh thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve this.

1. Use [`document.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to add a callback for the [*DOMContentLoaded*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded) event:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
  updateStateSelectColor();
});
function updateStateSelectColor(){
  var elm = document.getElementById("state");
  elm.style.color="green";
}
```

```html
<select id="state" onchange="updateStateSelectColor()" style="color: red">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="FL" selected>Florida</option>
</select>
```

And one could even bind the function directly to the event listener, but bear in mind that the function would receive a reference to the event as the first argument.

```
      document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", updateStateSelectColor);
```

2. Assign the function to the [`window.onload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) property

```js
window.onload = function(event) {
  updateStateSelectColor();
};
function updateStateSelectColor(){
  var elm = document.getElementById("state");
  elm.style.color="green";
}
```

```html
<select id="state" onchange="updateStateSelectColor()" style="color: red">
  <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
  <option value="FL" selected>Florida</option>
</select>
```

3. use the [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/body#attr-onload) attribute of the `<body>` tag
4. Invoke the function immediately after it is defined (as was described in [bassxzero's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048237/set-option-style-on-load-for-select-element#comment69304044_41048237)).